# Are there tools to generate a GUI using EclipseLink/JAXB? Can I access merged metadata?

Tags: java, xml, user-interface, jaxb, eclipselink

I am currently working on way to unify the representation of data in an application in the GUI and in file storage (XML).

My idea is to migrate the existing XML IO code to EclipseLink MOXy, which works really well as far I tested it. In our application we also use a generic GUI the builds itself using custom annotations on the domain objects. This self building GUI can be used to manipulate the application data (or parts of it).

The goal is to minimize the programming and maintenance effort. I want do write the actual domain class with some annotations and want the GUI to manipulate these object as well as the XML IO to be generated automatically (this works because it always follows the same scheme).

One way to do this would be to access the metadata EclipseLink/JAXB uses to turn Java objects into XML. If I could access the metadata for a given object, I would be able to create a generic GUI with data bindings. Additional hints could be passed via @XmlProperties.

Is it possible to access the merged metadata? Or are there already tools to achieve what I want to do?